# Android Sqlite Query syntax query error.Help need

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Pls check my syntax and correct me..

Am getting error 
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "BETWEEN30": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM TABLE_ITEMS WHERE date BETWEEN30/06/2017'AND'07/07/2017'

```
 String query = " SELECT * FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE date BETWEEN" + past_date + "'AND'" + current_date + "' " ;
```

Comment: you should use parameters

Comment: obviously even if you fix it ... it will not work at all as obviously sqlite has no date type and date in format `dd/MM/YYYY` doesn't sort well as string ... and there is no string between 30/06/2017 and 07/07/2017 as  30/06/2017 is greater than 07/07/2017 in terms of strings

Answer (score 1):

> A SQLite exception that indicates there was an error with SQL parsing
>   or execution.

Rectify your Statement using **`BLANK SPACE`** & **`Single-Double`** ***Character*** .

```
String query = " SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ITEMS + " WHERE date BETWEEN " + past_date + " AND " + current_date + "  ;
```

You can try with

```
 "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME+ " WHERE  date "+ BETWEEN past_date('"+DATE_STR_FORMAT+"') + " AND current_date " ('"+DATE_STR_FORMAT_CURRENT+"')"";
```

Comment: There is another problem which needs to be fixed: the `'` characters. They are 3. If the datatype is text you would require 4. If it is numeric, you would need none. Re-reading the question, it seems to be text (even if in a **wrong format**).

Comment: @all..wait.i will update

Comment: pls update.am still getting same error..

Comment: now getting Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "'AND'": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM TABLE_ITEMS WHERE date BETWEEN 30/06/2017'AND'07/07/2017'

Comment: Thank u..its working.. String query = " SELECT * FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE date BETWEEN " + past_date + " AND " + date + " " ;

Comment: i want to check one more condition in this query..how can i use "OR" clause..." WHERE date = '" + date + "'

Comment: @learner The correct format for text dates is `YYYY-MM-DD` (at least, ONE of the correct TimeStrings). You can get the full list on the SQLite official docs.

Comment: its working fine       String query = " SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ITEMS + " WHERE date BETWEEN " + past_date + " AND " + date + " " ;

Comment: @learner Follow step by step approach .